# Проблема с слиянием массивов Python

Tags: python, массивы

Я хочу "склеить" два массива,но при попытке их слить я получаю конечную часть с кавычками.

(data.txt)

```
5,4,6
```

(Code)

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
   array = [i.rstrip() for i in f]
   array1 = [1,5,8,9]
   result = array + array1
```

```
[1,5,8,9,5,4,6] (Желаемый результат)
```

```
[1,5,8,9,'5','4','6'] (Получаемый результат)
```

Comment: array = [int(i.rstrip()) for i in f] т.к. из txt вычитываются строки, а вам нужны инты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том что в `array` у вас находится строки, а не числа. Вам надо превратить число

```
array = [int(i.rstrip()) for i in f]
```

Если они записаны в одну строку через запятую то так:

```
line = f.readline()
array [int(el) for el in line.split(",")
```

Comment: Здравствуйте!Спасибо за ваш ответ,но после изменения строчки кода на вашу мне выводит ошибку "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5,4,6' "

Comment: @Helper изменил ответ